Use Authentication Cookies from Manual Session that Already Exists
Background
Using the selenider wrapper for chromote, I am scraping a webpage on Autotask, which has a login wall protected by 2FA.  Whenever I use open_url() on the webpage, I am redirected to the login...but upon login it takes me not to the webpage (via ?ReturnURL) but rather to the homepage.

Site: ww3.autotask.net
Webpage: https://ww3.autotask.net/Mvc/ServiceDesk/TicketNew.mvc/Create?categoryId=135
Login: https://ww3.autotask.net/Mvc/Framework/Authentication.mvc/Authenticate?ReturnUrl=%2fMvc%2fServiceDesk%2fTicketNew.mvc%2fCreate%3fcategoryId%3d135&categoryId=135
Homepage: https://ww3.autotask.net/Mvc/Framework/Navigation.mvc/Landing

Challenge
Because of the 2FA, I cannot automate login by either

using the user:password@domain convention; or
automating the entry of hardcoded credentials, via elem_click() and elem_send_keys().

As such, I must prompt the script user to log in manually:
library(httr)
library(selenider)

# ...

# Autotask page for ticket creation.
ticket_url <- modify_url("",
  scheme = "https",
  hostname = "ww3.autotask.net",
  path = "Mvc/ServiceDesk/TicketNew.mvc/Create",
  query = list(categoryId = 135)
)

# ...

# Open to the login wall for Autotask...
session <- open_url(ticket_url)
session$driver$view()

# ...then prompt user to log in...
did_log <- winDialog("okcancel",
  message = "Please log in to Autotask, and then hit OK."
)

# ...and proceed upon confirmation.
if (did_log == "OK") {
  session$driver$Page$navigate(ticket_url)
  
  # ...
}

Question
I know it is possible to grab cookies — including those for authentication — from one session via Network$getCookies(), and then pass them to another via Network$setCookies():
cookies_1 <- session_1$driver$Network$getCookies()

session_2$driver$Network$setCookies(cookies_1$cookies)

But is it possible to grab cookies from (say) an Autotask session, which is already open (manually) in Chrome?  Or is this limited to chromote sessions specifically?
I always have a tab open to Autotask, so this would eliminate the login prompt from the script, and let it proceed "under the hood".
